# Can't use request_irq() with "virtual" IRQs?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-device-driver, irq

I have a problem with request_irq() while porting a driver from kernel 3.14 to 4.1. Our driver is using an IRQ that is shared with a third-party driver that comes first at boot time.

When it was running on kernel 3.14, the IRQ was static and could be obtained using request_irq(), like so:

```
request_irq(irq_number, irq_handler,
    IRQF_SHARED | IRQF_TRIGGER_HIGH,
    "irq name", device_context);
```

But now on kernel 4.1, an interrupt-controller is making the IRQ "virtual" and I don't know how to get the IRQ. This interrupt-controller being used by the 3rd-party driver, I can't even think of discarding it and continue the old way with `request_irq()`.

The new "virtual" IRQ is not visible from:

```
cat /proc/interrupts
```

anymore (which I guess is fine).

I have browsed the web looking for examples, I have heard about `irq_domain` for example. But I have so little experience with Linux integration that I'm lost trying to figure out how to get the shared virtual IRQ.

How does one deal with shared virtual IRQs?

Comment: There is not enough context. 1. What the bus device connected to? 2. Where is the piece of code that related to `irq_number` variable? 3. Where is the output of `grep "irq name" /proc/interrupts` in both cases? And so on...